# Control cosole program from Python and pass commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I was wondering if it was possible (and how to do) to start an console program with `subprocess.Popen()` or something similar and output realtime output line by line, and pass commands to the command line process. I have worked and researched this, and tried over and over again, but cannot for the life of me accomplish it.

Any ideas for sample code? Say I wanted to output these to a log file in realtime, and pass commands with a graphical interface with buttons. Thanks.

Comment: Add what you have tried, do you know how to get data from the process in real time and/or to write to stdin?

Comment: Nothing really, all I know is how to start the process with Popen, and print to stdout. But I want to constantly update a string variable with each realtime output string.

Comment: `for line in proc.stdout:# use the line` will give you realtime output, `proc.stdin.write(b"whatever\n")` will write to the process

Comment: I need to have a loop in the program I'm using detecting each time the string is changed and printing that to the console, I don't want to use `stdout` because I want to reuse this code in other projects too, that may not use the console for output.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by *I don't want to use stdout because I want to reuse this code in other projects too*, if you want the output in realtime you are not going to be getting it any other way, if you want to write to a file you would direct stdout to a fie object but the first and second halves of your question seem to be contradictory.

Comment: Say I want to print this to a GUI element. Lets say to do that, I use `console.append(output_string)` where `output_string` is the latest output string from the console application. I also want to be able to pass commands to the application like I would do when typing the command in to the console window.

Comment: Like I said, you need to get any output from stdout and write any input to the prcoess stdin afert setting `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and  `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`, that or create your own pipe

Comment: How do I make my own pipe? and make each output string go into a variable string?

Comment: look at the [questions linked in the `subprocess` tag description that mention pexpect and the explanation for a block-buffering issue](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/subprocess/info)